# How to prevent accordion toggle when click on submit input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I can't figure out how to prevent default behaviour of `accordion` when I click on an icon which is a submit of `POST` form.

```
<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#record_309" class="accordion-toggle even">

                            <td>
                            </td>
                            ...
                            <td class="action">                                      
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <form class="col-lg-3" action="/dashboard/settings/" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="309">
        <input style="max-width:15px;" type="image" onclick="preventAccordion(event);" src="/static/icons/alarm-1.png">
    </form>
    <form class="col-lg-3" action="/products/reset/" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="<CSRFTOKEN>">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="309">
        <input style="max-width:15px;" type="image" src="/static/icons/restart.png">
    </form>    
</div>        
</td>        
</tr>
```

As you can see, in the first form of the last column, I'm trying to call `preventAccordion(e)` function to prevent showing the accordion. The problem is that `preventDefault(event)` is preventing form submit.

```
<script>
        window.preventAccordion = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
</script>
```

Do you know how to prevent accordion from toggling when user clicks on this icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `e.stopPropagation()` instead.

> Note that this will not prevent other handlers on the same element
>   from running.
>   http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/1o78c2os/2/